# Is it possible to respond to the author of a deleted question?

Tags: discussion, support

I awoke this morning to find [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808582/folders-disappearing-in-ubuntu-16-04?noredirect=1#comment1221819_808582) in my inbox. At some point between the author leaving the comment and my receiving it the original question was deleted by the author. I'm wondering if there is a way to respond to a comment on a deleted post, and if not why does the system leave them in my inbox if they are not actionable?

Comment: Get 2k more rep and you'll be good.

Comment: find another post of said user and pm him in comments?

Comment: @Rinzwind hard to do currently as my memory fails me as to the users name and I do not appear to be able to access that information.

Comment: @Zacharee1 This will come to pass eventually, but not today.. ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek :p. Give Rinzwind the link. He can give you the user.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/460716/saikumar @ElderGeek :+)

Comment: @Rinzwind Thank you for finding the user for me.

Comment: "finding"? That's a stretch ;-) I just visited the link

Comment: @Rinzwind Easy for you, lost for me. I suppose identifying would have been the better verb. The sentiment stands however.

Answer (score 2):

Once your reputation is high enough (10k +) you can access the information to determine who the author of a deleted post was, indicating that something that appears not to be actionable can be with the help of those who have access to said data.